GeoServer world image
I want to create a WMS layer using jpg + jgw + prj files. It's a very small area. I used the WorldImage store. The layer displays in the correct location, but when zooming in, the image seems to be shifted. How to fix it?



The bounds of the image seem the same but the image seems to have shifted in the bounds which is odd. Your best bet would be to convert it to a GeoTiff using gdal_translate - then you have a better tested rendering path and transparancey

Yes, I checked it but the problem is that I have a lot of such files also .pngs with  reference  and its a part of automated process.
